# Unify multiple Django url prefixes by pattern to same page

Tags: django, regex, django-urls

I have the following Django urls patterns:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('some.utils',
    url(r'^media$', logic0),
    url(r'^tickets$', logic1),
    url(r'^dogs$', logic2),
    url(r'^some-location-with-ending.png$', LOGIC3),
    url(r'^some-location-other-ending.svgh$', LOGIC3),
    url(r'^some-location-number-123$', LOGIC3),
    url(r'^some-location-5$', LOGIC3),
)
```

Is there a simple way (regex?) to unify all the `some-location` prefixes in one line? Of course also for future patterns that will start at `some-location`

Answer (score 0):

You can list them in an alternation `|`

```
^some-location-(?:with-ending\.png|other-ending\.svgh|number-123|5)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MRxVV8/1)

A bit less specific pattern could be matching `some-location-` and match the following word characters, optionally repeating the `-` before it and optionally matching an extension.

```
^some-location-\w+(?:-\w+)*(?:\.\w+)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d07PR5/1)

Comment: Thanks, have you tried this in Django urls? For me it's not working, maybe i'm missing something else... Also isn't there a simpler regex for just everything after `some-location-`? E.g. `^some-location-.*`

Comment: @MTZ4 I have not tried the pattern in Django urls. Are the current urls which are listed in the regex demo also not working? You can use `^some-location-.*` but that is a very broad pattern as `.*` will match any character except a newline and it will match also just `some-location-`

Comment: Yes, other regex are not working as well. I am using Django 1.6 might be related. Regex like `url(r'^mypath/(?P<path>.+)', ..)` do work well

Comment: If that works, perhaps it could be like this `url(r'^mypath/(?P<path>some-location-.*)', ..)` or `url(r'^(?P<path>some-location-.*)', ..)`